# implement a simple replace method and still get the capital words

Tags: javascript

I faced a simple but wired issue when I tried to replace a simple string:

```js
const reference = 'then Max have gone with Sara.'; 
const selector = 'sara'; 
const phrase = 'Joe';
    
const result = reference.toLowerCase().replace(selector, phrase);
console.log(result);
```

I have a `reference` string and I want to replace a `selector` with a `phrase`.

The issue is the selector may be all lowercase so I need to conver reference to all lowercase words to be able to implement the replace method on two all lowercase strings right?

Now the issue shows up... when I convert the reference to lowercase words then all capital words (like Max as a name!) turn to lower case unexpectedly...

How can I do the replace method and still get this result:

```
then Max have gone with Joe.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build a regular expression ([`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/)) with some flags, like `g` for global (replace all ocurrences) and `i` for case insensitive search.

This approach does not cover special characters, but all letters and digits.

```js
const
    reference = 'then Max have gone with Sara.',
    selector = 'sara',
    phrase = 'Joe',
    result = reference.replace(new RegExp(selector, 'gi'), phrase);
    
console.log(result);
console.log('foo.'.replace(new RegExp('.', 'gi'), '!')); // all chars are replaced
```

Comment: "This approach does not cover special characters, but all letters and digits." I don't understand????

Comment: for example `'.'` is a sign for any character in a regular expression. if the string contains a dot, any character at this place would match. please see above.

Comment: Got it... That's no problem in my case... I have always a phrase to replace.